# What is the right Stack Exchange site to ask a question related to Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to fix some Outlook junk filtering issues from the perspective of an end user; no programming involved. I posted to Stack Overflow and [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75426589/junk-email-filter-levels-no-longer-available-on-outlook) got closed. What is the right Stack Exchange site to ask this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't recall whether I did this on the web or desktop (currently running Outlook for Mac 16.69.1)

[Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com)  for the MacOS client. [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) for the web client